# Module not found when using rekuire, requirish, or rfr to solve nodejs require relative issue

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

I'd like to avoid the complex relative path issue described [here](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) by using one of the recommended solutions. I've come across three similar libraries:

- [rekuire](https://github.com/nadav-dav/rekuire)
- [node-rfr aka Require from Root](https://github.com/warmsea/node-rfr)
- [requirish](https://github.com/enricostara/requirish)

I've tried all three and all are failing with "module not found" or a similar error which makes me believe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I'm relatively inexperienced with npm/node. I'm only using node in the browser using browserify to bundle my app into a single JS file.

Here's my extremely simple hello world example:

*Structure:*

```
lib/Bob.js
app.js
```

*Bob.js*

```
function Bob() {
    return "I am bob";
}

module.exports = Bob;
```

*app.js*

```
var Bob = require('./lib/Bob.js');

console.log(Bob());
```

*Bundling into a single JS:*

```
browserify app.js -o bundle.js
```

Chrome's console successfully outputs "I am Bob".

---

Now if I try and of the libraries, let's say requirish:

**REQUIRISH:**

```
npm install requirish
```

*app.js changes*

```
'use strict';

require('requirish')._(module);
var Bob = require('lib/Bob');

console.log(Bob());
```

*Bundling changes*

```
browserify -t requirish app.js > bundle.js
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/lib/Bob' from '/Users/ngb/projects/MyApp/src/main/resources/public/js/hello'
at /Users/ngb/.nvm/v0.10.30/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:42:25
```

---

**RFR:**

```
'use strict';

var rfr = require('rfr');
var Bob = rfr('lib/Bob');

console.log(Bob());
```

*Building*

```
browserify app.js -o bundle.js -d
```

Chrome's console outputs the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'lib/Bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Browserify can find module by parse string "require".
If you want to use both side client and server, use [rfr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfr) for server side and [browserify-rfr](https://github.com/SamyPesse/browserify-rfr) for browserify's transform.

In my opinion, the "rfr" is the best because this module does not override original require.

------- Notice! Additional Information,
As today browserify-rfr version leaves my local file path to bundle.js. This may cause another problem, so I chose [requirish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirish). Since the requirish changes behavior of original require by pushing a new path to module.paths, you always notice that and alert your coworker!

thanks!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirish